# "its presence a mystery" ? Where is the predicate?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> There among the wildflowers lay a door, **its presence a mystery**. (From ACT)

I don't understand the grammatical construction after the comma (the bold text). It seems to me that it lacks a predicate, but even if adding a predicate "is," I think the comma should be adjusted to a period.
Another alternative I can think of is adding a participle "being", turning it into "its presence being a mystery."
Then again, I just do not understand the orginal construction of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an "is", but as you note, it would need to be a separate sentence.

The phrase "its presence a mystery" has "its presence" in apposition to "mystery", without an explicit copulative verb.

The whole phrase is an adjunct to the main sentence.

Comment: so " its presence a mystery" is in apposition? I think in that case, a comma is needed

Comment: The word "mystery" is essential to the meaning of "presence" which would have no meaning here without the appositive, so no comma should be used.  https://tinyurl.com/y64egtsn     "When an appositive is essential to the meaning of the noun it belongs to, don’t use commas. When the noun preceding the appositive provides sufficient identification on its own, use commas around the appositive."

Comment: Thanks, I see. But I suddenly feel like this structure is nominative absolute, is that right

Comment: Its meaning is linked to the to the word "door", and there's no participle, so I don't think it fits that description.